# Is it incorrect to put <img> and <a> tags into a <p> tag?

Tags: html

What I am trying to do is have a `<p>` element with the title of an image on the first line and a `<p>` element that contains `"by + the image of the author + the name of the author"`. The problem is that I'm not sure putting an `<img>` tag + `<a>` tag into the `<p>` tag is correct.

The bare bone of what I'm trying to do is this:

```
<p>Title<p>
<p>
    by <img src='#'><a href='#'>Author</a>
</p>
```

Comment: When you try this, does anything fail?  Have you run this through an HTML validator?  Is there an actual problem to be solved here?

Comment: Define *incorrect*. It is valid HTML but there may be better (semantic) ways, e.g. using `figure` and `figcaption` (not inside `p` tags, though). There is no single 'correct' way, though, and it is highly opinion-based. Therefore, this question is off topic.

Comment: The HTML validator is a good idea. And while this does work, it doesn't  necessarily mean it's correct. For some quite time I was using elements which were not <li> under <ul> and while it wasn't giving me any problems, I soon found out it was incorrect to have anything other than <li> under an <ul>. This is why I'm asking.

Comment: @Bobimaru — I've never seen a situation where the validator didn't report an error if you used a non-li element as a child of a ul.

Comment: Oh no, after reading what I wrote again I realized I worded it poorly. "And while this does work" was meant for my code, not the validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to HTML5 specification, [`<p>` element](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-p-element) should contain, so called, [phrasing content](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#phrasing-content). And it also says, that `<a>` and `<img>` are indeed phrasing content.

So yes, it's fine to do that, and it's completely valid.